# Calendar invitations in Outlook where only one person from group can accept

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a situation where someone from the technical team is required in a meeting, but it is not important which one it is - any of 3 different employees of the same level can attend and provide the information.

Is there a way in Outlook to send the invitation to the 3 people and when one of them accepts the meeting, it is automatically declined for the other two? This way the amount of discussion about who should attend is reduced as we don't have to check if someone is already attending etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge of Outlook there is no such feature. Rather, it should be communicated to this team that only one of them is required to attend the meeting in an email, or in person. You could perhaps invite them as optional rather than required attendees.

Comment: I think this is a case of the solution being far more complex (if possible at all) than the perceived problem they are trying to solve. I will advise them to speak to each other

Comment: Outlook has full support for VBA, just like any other Office product. But yes, once you get into programming a custom solution and hooking it together over Exchange and making everything work correctly, you probably should have just walked over and told them that one of them has to accept the invite and show up. :)